# Mongodb export, using the --query argument errors with incorrect query

Tags: mongodb, export

I am trying to export a certain set of records. but it errors claiming invalid JSON

```
mongoexport ... --type=csv --collection users --query '{"role": "Student"}' --out x.csv

error validating settings: query '[123 114 111 108 101 58 32 83 116 117 100 101 110 116 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
```

I dont know where the array of numbers is coming from - and the query is valid JSON

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? Please post the output of `mongod --version` and `mongoexport --version`

Comment: mongodb is ATLAS - Version 4.0.10
mongoexport version: r4.0.4
git version: f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839
Go version: go1.8.5
   os: windows
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Windows doesn't recognize single quotes as a "quote" character. Unlike UNIX, Windows treats single and double quotes differently.

Switch the quotes around and it should work:

```
mongoexport ... --query "{'role': 'Student'}" ...
```

Comment: good info - thanks - it worked...the one combo I didn't try because single quotes always kills me in a JSON validator...